# Keras model in Tensorflow.js: good predictions on images but awful on video?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have converted a custom Keras model to layersModel for Tensorflow.js. I tested the model by uploading an image and calling the prediction after upload was done. Snippet for prediction:

```
let img = document.getElementById('image')
let offset = tf.scalar(255)
let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(img).resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224]).toFloat().expandDims();
let tensorImg_scaled = tensorImg.div(offset)
prediction = await model.predict(tensorImg_scaled).data();
```

With this code, my predictions follow the original model, confidence values changing constantly like they should. However my intention is to analyze webcam feed every second. A function including this code is called every second:

```
const video = document.querySelector("video");
let offset = tf.scalar(255)
let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(video).resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224]).toFloat().expandDims();
let tensorImg_scaled = tensorImg.div(offset)
prediction = await model.predict(tensorImg_scaled).data();
```

With video I get awful results where the prediction is always something like Float32Array(3) [6.18722574920633e-16, 1, 3.5979095258653615e-8] - the middle confidence value always being 1 or 0,9999.

What could be the problem here? Calling the video prediction snippet more seldom - like every 5 seconds - does not help.

Any help with video predictions is super appreciated -  it is a final project to uni and the panic starts to creep in... Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though video is technically made of individual frames it has one important thing which is that those frames exist as a sequence of frames. Your model is not performing well because you trained it to do well on a single frame at a time. When dealing with video data you should be using a CONV(for spatial features) and then a LSTM(for temporal features).

In your case what you could do is implement a rolling prediction over K predictions i.e., the prediction at a frame is the average prediction over a certain number of predictions.